# What method should be used to solve the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation:
$$y^{2}dy = x\left ( x dy - y dx \right ) e^{\frac{x}{y}}$$

and I need to solve for a general solution. I'm getting stuck trying to solve for a general solution, as there is no definite Substitution that seems appropriate, and solving for $dy/dx$ is harder that I first thought.

What method should be applied to solve for $Y$ with independent variable $x$?

Comment: i think an explicit solution doesn't exist

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Ah. maybe that's why i'm having trouble. do you think there is a determinate implicit solution?

Comment: yes there is, have tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, and no matter how I input it, it will 'use the closest interpretation' (e^(x/y)). I also tried mathematica, but I do not think that the 'dy' and 'dx' tokens can be properly inputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We call a first order differential equation in the following form **homogeneous**:
>   $$y'=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
>   Using the change of variable $y=vx$, it becomes a separable differential equation.

Let's try and get your ODE in that form:
$$y^2 y'=x^2 e^{x/y} y'-xye^{x/y}$$
$$(y^2-x^2 e^{x/y})y'=-xye^{x/y}$$
$$y'=\frac{xye^{x/y}}{x^2 e^{x/y}-y^2}$$
Dividing both the numerator and denominator of the RHS by $x^2$, we obtain what we want:
$$y'=\frac{\frac{y}{x}e^{x/y}}{e^{x/y}-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$
Let's now apply the proposed substitution:
$$v+xv'=\frac{ve^{1/v}}{e^{1/v}-v^2} \iff v'=\frac{v^3}{x(e^{1/v}-v^2)} \tag{1}$$
Equation $(1)$ is clearly separable, as expected from our change of variable:
$$\int \frac{e^{1/v}-v^2}{v^3}~dv=\int \frac{1}{x}~dx$$
Integrating the RHS is easy. You can proceed with the left hand side by substituting $u=e^{1/v}$, and you should end up with a neat solution.

Comment: I see it now.  Before,  i had multiplied that y/x on the top out,  to get something real ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method, where we 'convert' the ODE into an [exact equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx) using an integrating factor, and then find the general solution.

---

We can easily write the equation in the following form:
$$M(x,y)~dx+N(x,y)~dy=0$$
Where $M(x,y)=xye^{x/y}$ and $N(x,y)=y^2-x^2 e^{x/y}$. Let's test if this equation is exact:
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=xe^{x/y}-\frac{x^2 e^{x/y}}{y}$$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-\frac{x^2 e^{x/y}}{y}-2xe^{x/y}$$
This is not an exact equation, since $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. Therefore, we must find an integrating factor to make the equation exact.

---

Since $\dfrac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}$ is a function of $y$ only, we know that we can assume that the integrating factor is in the form $\mu(y)$. It can be shown that the integrating factor in the above case is given by:
$$\mu(y)=\exp\left(\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}\right)$$
We thus find $\mu(y)=\dfrac{1}{y^3}$.

---

We now have an exact equation (Easily verifiable):
$$\frac{xe^{x/y}}{y^2}~dx+\frac{y^2-x^2 e^{x/y}}{y^3}~dy=0 \tag{1}$$
We thus know that there is some function $\psi(x,y)$ such that:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\partial \psi(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{xe^{x/y}}{y^2} \\ \frac{\partial \psi(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{y^2-x^2 e^{x/y}}{y^3} \end{cases} \tag{2}$$
The solution will be given by $\psi(x,y)=C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

---

To find this function $\psi(x,y)$, we can integrate $\frac{\partial \psi(x,y)}{\partial x}$ with respect to $x$:
$$\psi(x,y)=\int \frac{xe^{x/y}}{y^2}~dx=\frac{e^{x/y} (x-y)}{y}+g(y) \tag{3}$$
Where $g(y)$ is an arbitrary function of $y$. We can find $g(y)$ by evaluating the partial derivative of $\psi(x,y)$ with respect to $y$, and then substituting it into the second equation of $(2)$.